# Sniffing packets from a single executable

Tags: windows, sockets

I have found [SocketSniff](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/socket_sniffer.html) to be very useful for troubleshooting network applications (like web browsers, email clients, etc).  It can sniff wireless and loopback traffic without using a proxy or WinPCap.  It will show you only the traffic from the executable you select, which is exactly what I need.

I would love to build and extend a similar tool.  Does anyone know how this tool works?  Is there a simple SDK call to listen in on all TCP traffic from an executable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect that it uses code injection and [IAT patching](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/Win32APIHooking_Trouble.aspx) to hook the various winsock functions and then simply intercepts the calls and dumps the data that is being passed.

OR, it may use a [layered service provider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_Service_Provider)...